# How to lift the 100 user cap for OAuth to Google API for verified apps

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know why my app would have a 100 user cap, even though the Verification Status is "Published"? It says "the user cap will be in place until the app is verified by Google", but this is already the case. I would appreciate any insight.

[image: Screenshot of Google Console OAuth consent screen]

Comment: I think this is not immediate. Just to be sure, contact google support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 100 users cap is a quota limit for unverified scope requests, it is applied when the application tries to obtain access to scopes that have not been approved for the project during the app verification process, see [this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162). Since you're seeing this quota being actively used you should check whether the scopes requested by your application match the ones you submitted in the app verification status. In case there is a mismatch you would need to update the requested scopes and go through the verification process once again. Optionally you might also request a OAuth quota increase with this [support form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_quota_increase), but bear in mind there's no approval guarantee.

Finally, as Pievis pointed out this kind of inquiries would be better handled by Google Cloud Support team as they have the necessary information about your project to address your questions from end to end.

Comment: what are these 100 users cap? should it only be just one? Can you explain about it more?