# OAuth still limit 100 users, domain & scopes approved, no unverified app screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a problem with OAuth 100 limit users (per day?).

I'm using only: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly  scope

In url when login i see:
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

The status of my application is verified and publication set as "in production version"
[verification status - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4R0M.png)
**IN ENGLISH ON PICTURE:**
"*Verification status
Verified
Your consent screen has been verified. If you make changes that require verification later, you must resubmit your application for review. More information*"

But still have 100 user cap
[100 user cap screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odfei.png)
**IN ENGLISH ON PICTURE:**
"*Limits on the number of OAuth requests
Your user limit
The user limit limits the number of users that can grant access permissions to your application when requesting unapproved sensitive or restricted ranges. The user limit is valid for the lifetime of the project and cannot be reset or changed. Verified apps will still display the user limit on their pages, but this limit doesn't apply when you only request approved sensitive or restricted ranges. If users see an unverified app screen, your OAuth request includes additional scopes that have not been approved.
Danger
100 users / user limit is 100*"

During login via google my users don't have an Unverified App screen.

My readonly scope is verified as you can see on screen
[readonly verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmfOj.png)
**IN ENGLISH ON PICTURE:**
*My sensitive scopes:
/auth/youtube/.readonly
THIS SCOPE IS VERIFIED*

only readonly scope is needed when logging in via google.

I don't know what is going on, why I have still a limit 100 users' cap?

Comment: Please post pictures in English only.

Comment: added translation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lift the 100 user cap for OAuth to Google API for verified apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110486/how-to-lift-the-100-user-cap-for-oauth-to-google-api-for-verified-apps)

Comment: No, i have verified all scopes that my app uses.